# Why are the jumps of a pure jump-type process stopping times?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

Let $E$ be a topological space. Say that $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ is of *pure-jump type* if there is a nondecreasing $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\subseteq[0,\infty]$ with $\tau_0=0$ such that either

1. there is a $n_0\in\mathbb N$ with $$\tau_0<\cdots<\tau_{n_0}=\infty;\tag1$$ or
2. $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is increasing.

Moreover, $$\left|x\left([\tau_{n-1},\tau_n)\right)\right|\le1\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag2$$ and $$x(\tau_{n-1})\ne x(\tau_n)\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\text{ with }\tau_n<\infty\tag3.$$ In that case, $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_9}$ is called *jump sequence* of $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$.

> Now let $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued pure-jump tpye process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with jumping sequence $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$. How can we show that each $\tau_n$ is a stopping time with respect to the filtration $\mathcal F_t:=\sigma(X_s,s\le t)$, $t\ge0$, generated by $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$?

This claim is made on p. 277 of Kallenberg's book Foundations of Modern Probability (Third Edition). Actually, he is claiming that each $\tau_n$ is a stopping time with respect to the right-continuous filtration $(\mathcal F^+_t)_{t\ge0}$, but I don't know why we need the right-continuity. He writes that it would follow by a "simple approximation based on Lemma 9.3":

[image]

But I don't see how this Lemma could be useful here.

Comment: I'm not sure about the use of Lemma 9.3. Since $(x_t-x_0)_{t\geq0}$ is adapted and right-continuous it follows by Lemma 9.6 in Kallenberg that $\tau_1=\inf\{t>0\mid x_t-x_0\neq0\}$ is weakly optional. Then by Lemma 9.2 it is optional for the right-continuous filtration. For $\tau_2,\tau_3,\dotsc$ you can probably do the same with the restarted processes, e.g. $(x_{\tau_1+t}-x_{\tau_1})_{t\geq0}$.